# Angular 4/5 Form Group Validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a reactive form set up on my Angular app but I am trying to figure out if Angular 4/5 has a way to check if an input with a formControlName directive is valid or not.

I don't want to check if the whole form is valid - i know how to do this. I have a stepper process form and I want to disable the next button if it is invalid.

i.e. is there something like this for **form controls** and not just form groups?:

```
[disabled]="!formGroup.valid"
```

Comment: `this.fb.group({
                fieldID: fieldID,
                fieldname: field, 
                displayname: name});`
Each fromcontrol in this group has a valid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you declared your variables as form controls (i.e. out of a form group), you will have to use the form to access them.

To get the errors on it, use

```
[disabled]="formGroup.hasError('form control name', 'required')"
```

Or simplier

```
[disabled]="formGroup.get('form control name').hasError('required')"
```

Once you get the form control (with `formGroup.get`), you can do whatever you want with it. Testing for errors might be the easiest way to get if the control is valid or not.

To get a grip on every method available, you can use autocompletion from your IDE. In your typescript, create a `FormControl` variable, and see what you can do on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

[disabled]="!formGroup.get("myControlName").valid"

Comment: this doesn't work im afraid

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to solve this problem the wrong way. In a stepper form, you should create a reactive form for every step. That way you can check if every step is valid, by checking the status of this particular (step)form.

One implementation is demonstrated in the material2 library, they used this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check every input for errors. You can do it like this:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
       required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
       [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is using template driven forms and also i'm not after how to show errors. I'm more after a solution to disable a button in a stepper-process form if the input is not valid.. thanks

Comment: If you just want to display a single button based on a stepper, you could just take a number variable and change it on the button clicks. And your button would be disabled like this: `[disabled]="!stepper==1"` and do this with the next button `!stepper==2` and so on